# Problem with vis.js Network hierarchical layout

Tags: javascript, networking, vis.js, graphing

I have an example of a very simple hierarchical vis.js network, but it displays as a single line in the wrong direction.

The graph should display from left to right, but instead the entire network is displayed in a single vertical line.

I have tried many different options, but I cannot get it to display properly.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

```js
// create an array with nodes
var nodes = new vis.DataSet(
  [
    { id: 1,  value: 21, label: 'GR' },
    { id: 12, value: 10, label: 'PL' },
    { id: 18, value: 28, label: 'MM' },
    { id: 22, value: 12, label: 'I_STORE_LOCATOR' },
    { id: 23, value: 18, label: 'SL' },
        { id: 29, value: 3,  label: 'I_PRICEMATCH' },
        { id: 30, value: 6,  label: 'PM' }
  ]
);

// create an array with edges
var edges = new vis.DataSet(
  [
   {id: 13, eLabel: 100, arrows: "to", from: 1, to: 12, },
     {id: 26, eLabel: 100, arrows: "to", from: 1, to: 18, },
     {id: 17, eLabel: 100, arrows: "to", from: 12, to: 1, },
     {id: 32, eLabel: 60, arrows: "to", from: 18, to: 22, },
     {id: 47, eLabel: 60, arrows: "to", from: 18, to: 23, },
     {id: 53, eLabel: 30, arrows: "to", from: 18, to: 29, },
     {id: 62, eLabel: 30, arrows: "to", from: 18, to: 30, },
   {id: 34, eLabel: 120, arrows: "to", from: 22, to: 23, },
     {id: 40, eLabel: 60, arrows: "to", from: 23, to: 22, },
     {id: 43, eLabel: 120, arrows: "to", from: 23, to: 18, },
     {id: 55, eLabel: 30, arrows: "to",  from: 29, to: 30, },
     {id: 58, eLabel: 60, arrows: "to", from: 30, to: 18, }
  ]
);

// create a network
var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
var treeData = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges,
};

let options = {
    "layout": {
    "randomSeed": 2345,
    "improvedLayout":true,
    "clusterThreshold": 150,
    "hierarchical": {
      "enabled":true,
      "levelSeparation": 150,
      "nodeSpacing": 100,
      "treeSpacing": 200,
      "blockShifting": true,
      "edgeMinimization": true,
      "parentCentralization": true,
      "direction": 'LR',        // UD, DU, LR, RL
      "sortMethod": 'directed',  // hubsize, directed
      "shakeTowards": 'leaves'  // roots, leaves
    }
  }
};

var network = new vis.Network(container, treeData, options);

network.on('click', function (properties) {
  var ids = properties.nodes;

  // ids is an array, loop through the items
  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
    treeData.nodes.update({id:ids[i],hidden:true})
  }      
});
```

```css
#mynetwork {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis-network/9.1.2/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis-network/9.1.2/dist/dist/vis-network.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The network is unable to determine the correct positioning for the hierarchy as it contains cycles (edges in both directions). A note on this can be found in the official example at https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/layout/hierarchicalLayoutMethods.html...

> Also note that it's impossible to properly position a "hierarchy" with a cycle (If node 1 is above node 2 and node 2 is above node 1 which one is actually on top?)

Removing the edges which loop back causing cycles (edges 17, 40, 43 and 58) allows the hierarchy to display correctly as per the snippet below. If these edges are required then I don't believe it's possible to use hierarchical layout in vis-network.

```js
// create an array with nodes
var nodes = new vis.DataSet(
  [
    { id: 1,  value: 21, label: 'GR' },
    { id: 12, value: 10, label: 'PL' },
    { id: 18, value: 28, label: 'MM' },
    { id: 22, value: 12, label: 'I_STORE_LOCATOR' },
    { id: 23, value: 18, label: 'SL' },
    { id: 29, value: 3,  label: 'I_PRICEMATCH' },
    { id: 30, value: 6,  label: 'PM' }
  ]
);

// create an array with edges
var edges = new vis.DataSet(
  [
   {id: 13, eLabel: 100, arrows: "to", from: 1, to: 12, },
     {id: 26, eLabel: 100, arrows: "to", from: 1, to: 18, },
     //{id: 17, eLabel: 100, arrows: "to", from: 12, to: 1, },
     {id: 32, eLabel: 60, arrows: "to", from: 18, to: 22, },
     {id: 47, eLabel: 60, arrows: "to", from: 18, to: 23, },
     {id: 53, eLabel: 30, arrows: "to", from: 18, to: 29, },
     {id: 62, eLabel: 30, arrows: "to", from: 18, to: 30, },
   {id: 34, eLabel: 120, arrows: "to", from: 22, to: 23, },
     //{id: 40, eLabel: 60, arrows: "to", from: 23, to: 22, },
     //{id: 43, eLabel: 120, arrows: "to", from: 23, to: 18, },
     {id: 55, eLabel: 30, arrows: "to",  from: 29, to: 30, },
     //{id: 58, eLabel: 60, arrows: "to", from: 30, to: 18, }
  ]
);

// create a network
var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
var treeData = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges,
};

let options = {
    "layout": {
    "randomSeed": 2345,
    "improvedLayout":true,
    "clusterThreshold": 150,
    "hierarchical": {
      "enabled":true,
      "levelSeparation": 150,
      "nodeSpacing": 100,
      "treeSpacing": 200,
      "blockShifting": true,
      "edgeMinimization": true,
      "parentCentralization": true,
      "direction": 'LR',        // UD, DU, LR, RL
      "sortMethod": 'directed',  // hubsize, directed
      "shakeTowards": 'leaves'  // roots, leaves
    }
  }
};

var network = new vis.Network(container, treeData, options);

network.on('click', function (properties) {
  var ids = properties.nodes;

  // ids is an array, loop through the items
  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
    treeData.nodes.update({id:ids[i],hidden:true})
  }      
});
```

```css
#mynetwork {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis-network/9.1.2/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis-network/9.1.2/dist/dist/vis-network.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if there is a way to specify the level of a node?  I already know what level I want each node to display at.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there not a way to specify the level of a node, it's determined by the edges and other options.

Comment: FYI I found this example where they set level and it works pretty good.

https://jsfiddle.net/laike9m/5gvh0ya4/2/

Comment: Good find, I wasn't aware of that but it is covered in the node documentation [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/nodes.html?keywords=level).